# React JS is not building the div inside my return statement in map rendering

Tags: requirejs, reactjs

Return statement part inside my map function is getting returned. Below is my code sample

```
render: function () {
        var primaryDealersAreaData = this.state.dealersList.map(function (dealer){
            console.log(dealer.DealerID);
            return
            ( 
                        <PrimaryDealerSettingsArea dealerId = {dealer.DealerID}
                                                    dealerName = {dealer.DealerName}
                                                    dealerContactPhone = {dealer.DealerContactPhone}
                                                    isLocSrpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isLocSrpVisible}
                                                    isLocVdpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isLocVdpVisbile}
                                                    isPhoneSrpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isPhoneSrpVisible}
                                                    isPhoneVdpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isPhoneVdpVisible}
                                                    siteName = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.siteName}
                                                    primaryDealerId = {this.state.primaryDealerId}
                                                    primaryWebsiteId = {this.state.websiteId}/>

            );
        });
```

in the above code sample dealersList is an Javascript array object and I am trying to send each of it using map to another Javascript file and in my return I am calling that primaryDealersAreaData and I am getting an empty div with no errors
 my return statement is as follows

```
return(
           <div className="page-area float-l">
                <div className="page-defaults-area float-l" id="PrimaryDealers">
                    {primaryDealersAreaData}
                  </div>
            </div>
            );
```

I am facing this problem from couple of days and I tried in different approaches and none of them actually worked.
Help appreciated.

Comment: How many times does `console.log(dealer.DealerID);` fire?

Comment: Also could you try to create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, try moving your return's opening parenthesis up to the same line as the return.

```
return ( 
                     <PrimaryDealerSettingsArea dealerId = {dealer.DealerID}
                                                dealerName = {dealer.DealerName}
                                                dealerContactPhone = {dealer.DealerContactPhone}
                                                isLocSrpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isLocSrpVisible}
                                                isLocVdpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isLocVdpVisbile}
                                                isPhoneSrpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isPhoneSrpVisible}
                                                isPhoneVdpVisible = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.isPhoneVdpVisible}
                                                siteName = {dealer.sharedInventorySettings.siteName}
                                                primaryDealerId = {this.state.primaryDealerId}
                                                primaryWebsiteId = {this.state.websiteId}/>

);
```

A return will return something that is on the same line. Since there's nothing there, your return is coming back as undefined.

Comment: A return will return something that is on the same line. Since there's nothing there, your return is coming back as undefined.

Comment: My bad, I thought the parenthesis was a curly brace for a second there.

Comment: ...which would have also been invalid.  Haha.  Slow morning.

Comment: That helps and I didn't realize that. Thanks a ton

Comment: No worries, happy Monday!